# Choose text appearing in taskbar

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have a c# application and have thought it could be fancy that it displayed current time. So I used form.text property of my main form and put the time into it (picture A)

Unfortunately when I point to the application icon in taskbar in Windows 7 it shows my time where it should show application name (picture B)

[image]

Is it possible to have some text on main form top bar and still display different text in Windows taskbar?

Comment: but how is it possible when you will point your mouse to your application icon on taskbar it will show the text of form and in your case that is time.you can set time + "another name of the form" as text property of form.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4 the [TaskbarItemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class was introduced. Unfortunately it does not directly support changing the application title show in the taskbar.

However, you might be able to achieve this using the [Windows API Code Pack library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). Yochay Kiriaty wrote an article called [Developing for the Windows 7 Taskbar – Application ID](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/06/18/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-application-id.aspx) which shows an example of what you might be trying to achieve.